# Does calling functions of an element of an `std::vector` which gets reallocated during the function call cause trouble?

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, stdvector, function-call

I have a `std::vector` of `GameObject`s. I access these `GameObject`s using direct pointers to them. (Don't worry about the pointers getting invalidated, I update the pointers when the `vector` realocates itself). The `GameObject` class has a function called `load()`.

So, in one case, I call the `load()` of an instance of `GameObject` which is stored within the `vector`. This function pushes another `GameObject` at the back of the `vector`. This causes the `vector` to run out of memory and reallocate.(or resize). Now, then that call to `push_back` returns, the `load()` is not able to access any of the `GameObject` instance's members any more. The instance still exists on the same vector though.

Why is the function not able to access the members? The members seen by the `load` contain junk/incorrect values. Any explanations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vector` can't do magic. It has to move elements, either by using their move constructors (if possible) or copy constructors, and then destroy the old objects in the previous location.

So, in your case, `GameObject::~GameObject` will be called for the object on which you called `GameObject::load`. Sure, there's another logically identical object **elsewhere**, but your `this` pointer is invalid when `load` returns. There's no way that `vector` can update your `this` pointer while a call is in progress.

Comment: hmmm... thats something to think about. I'll have to use a different container...Just asking, any ideas about what to do in this case?

Comment: `std::deque` also has O(1) random access but doesn't reallocate.